# Stop YouTube from changing my quality settings on full screen

Tags: youtube

Whenever I click "full screen" on YouTube, it changes the "quality settings" from 240p to 480p. I prefer to control the quality setting myself, and not have it influenced by the full screen button.

Is there a way to stop this? A Greasemonkey script perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially you can't and there are a lot of requests for that in [Google Forums](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=+site%3agoogle.com+quality+settings+full+screen+youtube).

One of the [Google Employees](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=7cf6f803fe409d69&hl=en) says:

> There are a few different options if
>   you login, then choose "settings" in
>   the drop down where you select quality
>   (right under the video player):
>
> - I have a slow connection. Never play
>     higher-quality video.
> - Always choose
>     the best option for me based on my
>     player size.
> - Always play HD when
>     switching to fullscreen (when
>     available)

You can try one of the [scripts](http://userscripts.org/search?cref=http%3A%2F%2Fuserscripts.org%2Fcse.xml&cof=FORID%3A9&q=youtube+quality&x=0&y=0) to find the one that suits you best.

Comment: Too bad that option does not work (nor ever has). It think it’s a placebo button. Stupid Google.

Answer (score 1):

Try these Firefox add-ons:

1. [YouTube quality manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-quality-manager/?src=search)
2. [Smartvideo for YouTube](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smartvideo-for-youtube-mytube/?src=search)

Both can be a bit buggy though.

Alternatively, you can just click the settings icon on the YouTube video itself and choose the video quality you want before you hit the fullscreen button for **every** video you watch.